# What does `value >= value` do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, conditional-statements, idioms, comparison-operators

Below is one of conditional statements from the source code of [d3.min](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/src/min.js).
What is this checking for?:

```js
value >= value
```

Here is the entire source code:

```js
export default function min(values, valueof) {
  let min;
  if (valueof === undefined) {
    for (const value of values) {
      if (value != null
          && (min > value || (min === undefined && value >= value))) {
        min = value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    let index = -1;
    for (let value of values) {
      if ((value = valueof(value, ++index, values)) != null
          && (min > value || (min === undefined && value >= value))) {
        min = value;
      }
    }
  }
  return min;
}
```

Comment: It might be a bug. `value` will never be larger than `value`. I'd suggest asking on d3's github page - if it's intentional you'd expect a good programmer to have left a comment explaining the odd code.

Comment: `undefined` and `NaN` will both cause this expression to evaluate as false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *could* be a peculiar form of checking against NaN (EDIT: and undefined):

```js
const foo = 0/0; // NaN
let bar;
console.log(foo >= foo);
console.log(bar >= bar);
```

<s>Although why would anyone write it like that, instead of using the `isNaN` method, I cannot tell.</s> It's shorter than, say `!isNaN(value) && value !== undefined`, but I'm not sure the tradeoff in legibility is worth it.

Comment: It also evaluates false for `undefined`

Comment: @phuzi Ah, thank you! Now we can kind of see the profit: the code gets shorter in comparison to doing those two checks explicitly. Though a little obfuscated.

Comment: "I'm not sure the tradeoff in legibility is worth it." - No it's not worth it, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `>=` comparison table created with editing [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G943v/16/).
You can see `value >= value` is `true` except when `value = undefined` or `value = NaN`:

[image]